# WPF KeyBinding Guesture for Ctrl+Shift+Zero not working

Tags: wpf, winapi, windows-7, windows-vista, key-bindings

I am trying to do a  to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> with WPF 3.5sp1, but the binding does not fire.  The XAML I'm using is:

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+D0" Command="Blah"/>
```

I have also tried:

```
<KeyBinding Key="D0" Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Command="Blah" />
```

And many other combinations, none of which work.   Gesture="Ctrl+D0" works great, or "Ctrl+Shift+OemPlus", etc. so I don't think my syntax is the issue.  I have looked at the Key enum and tried to see if "Shift-D0" is remapped into something like "OemParen" but nothing is jumping out at me.

I've even put a PreviewKeyDown handler on my Window, and I never see a KeyEvent where Key == D0 and Keyboard.ModifierKeys == <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>!   In fact, the D0 keydown never arrives at all when I am holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.PreviewKeyDown += MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown;
}

void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("shift is down!");
    }
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("key: {0}, system key: {1}, modifiers {2}", e.Key, e.SystemKey, e.KeyStates));
}
```

Comment: I have discovered that this is NOT a WPF issue, but the question itself is still valid and the answer does not seem to be well known.  How should I update the quesiton summary to reflect this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've discovered the problem.  The culprit is an Internationalization change made in Vista (that Win7 inherits) related to how keyboard layouts are changed.  There is a [KB topic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967893) discussing this issue and work arounds:

[Input method editor keyboard shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>) switches the input language in Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967893)